# Performant matching of substring with several words in string - Python

Tags: python, string, algorithm, boyer-moore

I'm working on a project and haven't found any useful resources for how to match substrings with several words to a string.

For example:
`substring = "I can be found in this string"`
in
`string = "Now, I can be found in this string example"`

I cannot use the `.find()` method or regex and to make things more complicated, the edge cases include:

`"reflexion mirror"` doesn't match `"'reflexion mirror'"` but does match `"(reflexion mirror)"`

`"maley"` doesn't match `"o'maley"`

`"luminate"` matches `"'''luminate"`

`"luminate"` matches `"luminate__"`

`"george`" doesn't match `"georges"`

Whenever characters bookend a string, like `"__hello world__"` or `"''hello world''"`, it doesn't interfere with matching `"hello"` or `"world"`

I'm using Boyer Moore to find the substrings which works except for these seemingly conflicting edge cases. Oh yeah, I also forget to mention that this solution is supposed to emphasize performance in time complexity.

I'm using `word.translate({ord(c): None for c in string.whitespace}).lower()` to preprocess my strings and substrings, which results in something like this:

`"asuggestionboxentryfrombobcarterdearanonymous,i'mnotquitesureiunderstandtheconceptofthis'anonymous'suggestionbox.ifnoonereadswhatwewrite,thenhowwillanythingeverchangebutinthespiritofgoodwill,i'vedecidedtooffermytwocents,andhopefullykevinwon'tstealit(ha,ha).iwouldreallyliketoseemorevarietiesofcoffeeinthecoffeemachineinthebreakroom.'milkandsugar','blackwithsugar','extrasugar'and'creamandsugar'don'toffermuchdiversity.also,theselectionofdrinksseemsheavilyweightedinfavorof'sugar'.whatifwedon'twantanysugar?"`

Any ideas as to how I can account for these edge cases??

Thanks

**Edit**

There is a caveat that `'` is to be treated as a character

Here is the unit test which I'm gathering the edge cases from:

```
class TestCountoccurrencesInText(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_count_occurrences_in_text(self):
        """
        Test the count_occurrences_in_text function
        """
        text = """Georges is my name and I like python. Oh ! your name is georges? And you like Python!
Yes is is true, I like PYTHON
and my name is GEORGES"""
        # test with a little text.
        self.assertEqual(3, count_occurrences_in_text("Georges", text))
        self.assertEqual(3, count_occurrences_in_text("GEORGES", text))
        self.assertEqual(3, count_occurrences_in_text("georges", text))
        self.assertEqual(0, count_occurrences_in_text("george", text))
        self.assertEqual(3, count_occurrences_in_text("python", text))
        self.assertEqual(3, count_occurrences_in_text("PYTHON", text))
        self.assertEqual(2, count_occurrences_in_text("I", text))
        self.assertEqual(0, count_occurrences_in_text("n", text))
        self.assertEqual(0, count_occurrences_in_text("reflexion mirror", "I am a senior citizen and I live in the Fun-Plex 'Reflexion Mirror' in Sopchoppy, Florida"))
        self.assertEqual(1, count_occurrences_in_text("Linguist", "'''Linguist Specialist Found Dead on Laboratory Floor'''"))
```

Comment: Do you have a set of exact rules to go with the examples? I'm unsure about why "reflexion mirror" does not match "'reflexion mirror'" when "luminate" matches "'''luminate"...is it because the non-alpha characters are on both sides without having an even number on each side, like in your bookending example, or is there a different rule?

Comment: The only rules are what I've been able to ascertain by looking at the pre-populated unit tests to see what should pass or fail. The examples of "maley" not matching "o'maley", "relfexion mirror" not matching "'reflexion mirror'" and "luminate" matching "'''luminate" seems to present contradictory logic. I will include the unit tests to hopefully clarify things

Comment: Why can't you use `.find` or regular expressions? Is this a homework assignment? If so, surely there's a better description available to you than the above?

Comment: @Grismar it is a take home. My instructions are that ```.find``` will fail the unit test and that regex won't be fast enough to meet their speed benchmark. This all the info I have been given